# Is it possible to use a mask in ITK to register two images?

Tags: python, image-processing, itk, image-registration

I would like to know wether it is possible or not to use two binary masks (one for each image) to register two images using Simple ITK?

Indeed, I need to register 2 images which have already been geo-referenced (pixels which do not contain data are filled with '0') but where a projection error still exists.

So, I only want to use pixels whose mask values are '1' in the computation of the similarity metric.

Here is my piece of code:

```
fixed = sitk.ReadImage('#######/imgRef.png', sitk.sitkFloat32);
moving = sitk.ReadImage('#######/imgRep.png', sitk.sitkFloat32)
maskFixed = sitk.ReadImage('#######/maskRef.png', sitk.sitkUInt8)
maskMoving= sitk.ReadImage('#######/maskRep.png', sitk.sitkUInt8)

# Handle optimizer
R = sitk.ImageRegistrationMethod()

# Restrict the evaluation of the similarity metric thanks to masks
R.SetMetricFixedMask(maskFixed)
R.SetMetricMovingMask(maskMoving)

# Set metric as mutual information using joint histogram
R.SetMetricAsMattesMutualInformation(numberOfHistogramBins=255)

# Gradient descent optimizer
R.SetOptimizerAsRegularStepGradientDescent(learningRate=0.01, minStep=1e-5, numberOfIterations=100, gradientMagnitudeTolerance=1e-8)

#R.SetOptimizerScalesFromPhysicalShift()

R.SetMetricSamplingStrategy(R.REGULAR) #R.RANDOM

# Define the transformation (Rigid body here)

transfo = sitk.CenteredTransformInitializer(fixed, moving, sitk.Euler2DTransform())

R.SetInitialTransform(transfo)

# Define interpolation method
R.SetInterpolator(sitk.sitkLinear)

# Add command to the registration process
R.AddCommand(sitk.sitkIterationEvent, lambda: command_iteration(R))
R.AddCommand(sitk.sitkStartEvent, lambda: start_plot())
R.AddCommand(sitk.sitkEndEvent, lambda: end_plot())
R.AddCommand(sitk.sitkIterationEvent, lambda: current_plot(R))
# Perform registration
outTx = R.Execute(fixed, moving)

print(outTx)
print("--------")
print("Optimizer stop condition: {0}".format(R.GetOptimizerStopConditionDescription()))
print("Number of iterations: {0}".format(R.GetOptimizerIteration()))
print("--------")

# Perform transformation and resample the moving image

# Save transformation as tfm file
sitk.WriteTransform(outTx, '/home/egs/f_nicolas/CODES_THESE/transfo_final.tfm')
#sitk.Show(transfo.GetDisplacementField(),"Displacement field")

# Resample moving image according to the last transformation
resampler = sitk.ResampleImageFilter()
resampler.SetReferenceImage(fixed)
resampler.SetInterpolator(sitk.sitkLinear)
#resampler.SetDefaultPixelValue(100)
resampler.SetTransform(outTx)
out = resampler.Execute(moving)
```

I hope someone could help!

Comment: Why do you think it is not working? Can you share your data? What is the output?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it by this code
Newfixed=fixed*fixedmask;
Newmoving=moving*movingmask;

And do the registration using newfixed an d newmoving

Comment: Please edit your post so that the code is formatted.

Answer (score -1):

I know you can do this in ITK, but I am unsure if it is possible in Simple ITK. It may not have all of ITK's features.

In the C++ implementation, you can do the following:

```
int Dimension = 3;
typedef itk::ImageMaskSpatialObject< Dimension > MaskObjectType;

itk::NormalizedMutualInformationHistogramImageToImageMetric<ImageType, ImageType> NMIMetricType;

NMIMetricType::Pointer nmiMetric = NMIMetricType::New();

// fixedImageMask is a pointer to a binary ITK image
// ITK ignores pixels that are 0 and only uses non-zero pixels
fixedMaskObject->SetImage( fixedImageMask ); 

nmiMetric->SetFixedImageMask(fixedMaskObject.GetPointer()); //fixedMaskObject is a MaskObjectType
```

Comment: The SetFixedImageMask() and SetMovingImageMask() are also available in SimpleITK, I added my current ode in my question.

Comment: In the C++ implementation of ITK, you need to construct a MaskSpatialObject from the mask image, prior to adding it to the registration. I do not see you doing that in the Python wrapper, but maybe that is handled under the hood.

Right now, with your current implementation, how do you know that the mask is not being set?

Also, I am not sure why I got a downvote on my answer!

Comment: SetFixedImageMask() and SetMovingImageMask() directly use a binary image without constructing a MaskSpatialObject.

Comment: OK, how do you know that the mask is not being set? I think Bradley has a point:

http://itk-users.7.n7.nabble.com/ITK-users-How-to-use-a-binary-mask-in-a-registration-process-td36126.html#a36137

Comment: I down voted this response because the original post was asking about implementing using SimpleITK and this response was uninformed about currently available features in SimpleITK. So I didn't think is was useful to solving the problem.

Comment: I'va added results to illustrate the issue (the algorithm tends to maximize the overlapping, while, in my application, I do not need this. http://itk-users.7.n7.nabble.com/ITK-users-How-to-use-a-binary-mask-in-a-registration-process-td36126.html#a36137